# Using count in a Subquery

Tags: mysql

Im currently learning about sub querys in mysql and just want to clarify if im on the right track. The below code does bring a result but im unsure if im doing it correctly. The question is

"Find a code and company name of all customers who submitted at least one order in April 1997 using an IN statement ."

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE, COMPANY_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMER_CODE IN (SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE
     FROM ORDERS
        WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN  '1997-04-01' AND '1997-04-30'
        GROUP BY CUSTOMER_CODE )
```

I went through the values that are inserted into the tables and it just doesnt seem to be correct even though a result is produced.

(Side note, is using a EXIST clause the same as a IN clause, but instead of WHERE CUSTOMER_CODE IN it is WHERE EXISTS ?

I tried this

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE, COMPANY_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE
     FROM ORDERS
        WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN  '1997-04-01' AND '1997-04-30'
        GROUP BY CUSTOMER_CODE );
```

these are the two talbes im using

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
    CUSTOMER_CODE   VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
    COMPANY_NAME    VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    CONTACT_NAME    VARCHAR(30),
    CONTACT_TITLE   VARCHAR(30),
    ADDRESS         VARCHAR(60),
    CITY        VARCHAR(15),
    REGION      VARCHAR(15),
    POSTAL_CODE     VARCHAR(10),
    COUNTRY         VARCHAR(15),
    PHONE       VARCHAR(24),
    FAX         VARCHAR(24),
    CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMER PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_CODE)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
    ORDER_ID        DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL,
    CUSTOMER_CODE   VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
    EMPLOYEE_ID     DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL,
    ORDER_DATE      DATE        NOT NULL,
    REQUIRED_DATE   DATE,
    SHIPPED_DATE    DATE,
    SHIP_VIA        VARCHAR(40),
    FREIGHT         DECIMAL(10,2)           DEFAULT 0,
    SHIP_NAME       VARCHAR(40),
    SHIP_ADDRESS    VARCHAR(60),
    SHIP_CITY       VARCHAR(15),
    SHIP_REGION     VARCHAR(15),
    SHIP_POSTAL_CODE    VARCHAR(10),
    SHIP_COUNTRY    VARCHAR(15),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ORDERS PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER_CODE FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_CODE) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_CODE),  
    CONSTRAINT FK_EMPLOYEE_ID FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID),  
    CONSTRAINT FK_SHIP_VIA FOREIGN KEY (SHIP_VIA) REFERENCES SHIPPER(COMPANY_NAME)  
);
```

but i recieve an empty set 
Thankyou all for your time

Comment: Are you saying the query gets you incorrect results, int's not clear from your question? On a more general note, when doing a subquery like that it is better to use  DISTINCT to avoid duplicate values in the IN, `SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_CODE...`

Comment: I return results but im just unsure if im doing it correct. Also is the distinct in the first select or in the subquery?

Comment: I meant the sub-query.

Comment: A group by without any aggregation functions is always a bit suspect. You should consider a join (not a subquery) with a group by and having clause.

Comment: The task asks us to use nested selects

Comment: Agh-being taught to do it the 'wrong' way. If you must us an in clause drop the group by and select distinct instead.

Comment: Thankyou for the advice ill change it. Also could you asist me with EXISTS function. is it a similar process but instead of  but instead of WHERE CUSTOMER_CODE IN it is WHERE EXISTS ?

Answer (score 1):

instead of a IN clause  you could use   a INNER JOIN  based on the same subquery ..

usually this perform better  that a In clause

```
  SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE, COMPANY_NAME
  FROM CUSTOMER
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_CODE
      FROM ORDERS
      WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN  '1997-04-01' AND '1997-04-30'
  ) t on t.CUSTOMER_CODE = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CODE
```

You should not use group by for when you don't use aggregation function (this don't work by default in most recent version of mysql)
use DISTINCT if you need  only distinct result

Comment: They want us to use an IN Clause and then a NOT IN clause :/

Comment: the inner join is equivalent  to a IN clause  not a NOT IN  ..  if you need  a NOT IN clause the you could use a NOT EXISTS .... anyway  comment seems not coherent with your question

Comment: I mean In and not in are two seperate querys, Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: i also need to use a NOT EXISTS clause for the same Results. See my edited question

Comment: You comment is not clear  .. your code  is about a subquery based  on IN clause  .. (your question not mention NOT IN clause)    you should take a look at  the difference  between IN  .. NOT IN  .. EXISTS and NOT EXISTS  .. and as suggested  by my answer  at the equivalent result for INNER JOIN  ..  ..

Comment: I named it that because i thought the way i selected the columns was incorrect. again sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1):

You must use EXISTS instead of NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT c.CUSTOMER_CODE, c.COMPANY_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER c
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE FROM ORDERS
  WHERE 
  CUSTOMER_CODE = c.CUSTOMER_CODE
  AND
  ORDER_DATE BETWEEN '1997-04-01' AND '1997-04-30'
);
```

You can also check about the `ORDER_DATE` with this:

```
YEAR(ORDER_DATE) = 1997 AND MONTH(ORDER_DATE) = 4
```

You can also do it with IN:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE, COMPANY_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMER_CODE IN (
  SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE FROM ORDERS
  WHERE YEAR(ORDER_DATE) = 1997 AND MONTH(ORDER_DATE) = 4 
);
```

If you want to *find the total number of all customers who submitted no orders*:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.CUSTOMER_CODE) AS COUNTER
FROM CUSTOMER c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE FROM ORDERS
  WHERE CUSTOMER_CODE = c.CUSTOMER_CODE
)
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt get the same results as using a IN

Comment: Can you post sample data? Because these 2 statements should return the same results although EXISTS is usually more efficient.

Comment: do you want the tables?

Comment: Anything that is indicative of the data you are querying so to see why these 2 queries do not return the same results.

Comment: EDITED: I added the two tables im using!

Comment: Fine, but the 2 above queries, with EXISTS and with IN, should return the same results. Are you sure that you executed these exact queries?

Comment: its my non exists that doesnt have any records. its under i tried this

Comment: Don't use NOT EXISTS, it will give the opposite results. Use my query with EXISTS

Comment: so if i wanna do "Find the total number of all customers who submitted no orders" its EXISTS not NOT EXISTS?